# Uniform and point wise convergent

Tags: real-analysis

What is the difference between point wise convergence and uniform convergence?
Can you explain the answer geometrically?

Answer (score 5):

You can easily visualize the difference form functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ by looking at their graph:

- In pointwise convergence you have that for every $x_{0}$ the point $(x_{0},f_{n}(x_{0}))$ "get closer" to the point $(x_{0},f(x_{0}))$ along the vertical.
- In uniform convergence you have something stronger: it morally means that you can take a "tube" around the graph of $f(x)$ in $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$, small as you like, and the graph of $f_{n}(x)$ will always be in that "tube" for large enough $n$.

Answer (score 0):

We say a function $f_n$ converges pointwise to $f$, if for a fixed $x$, as $n \rightarrow \infty$, $f_n(x) \rightarrow f(x)$.

For uniform convergence, it is required that for *all* $x$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ $f_n \rightarrow f$. You can think of this as a 'tube' around the function: as $n \rightarrow \infty$, $f_n$ is contained within this 'tube' about $f$ (in fact it is a $\epsilon$ distance surrounding $f$.

As an example, consider the function $f_n(x) = x^n$, for $x = 1$, $f_n(1) \rightarrow 1$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$, so $f_n$ converges pointwise to $1$ for $x = 1$.

However, for say $x=2$, $f_n(2) \rightarrow \infty$, as $n \rightarrow \infty$, so it is not uniformly convergent, as it does not converge to the same 'thing' for *all* $x$.

Comment: Well said, may you perhaps edit in the symbolic representation of them, for a fully enclosed answer: 
------
Uniform
------
>"\forall \epsilon \gt, \exists N \in \mathbb{N}, \forall n \geq N, \forall x \in \Omega, |f_n(x) - f(x)| \lt \epsilon"
------
Pointwise
------
>"\forall \epsilon \gt, \forall x \in \Omega, \exists N \in \mathbb{N}, \forall n \geq N, |f_n(x) - f(x)| \lt \epsilon"

Comment: I find this misleading. The point with pointwise convergence (if we talk about it on an interval as is usually the case) is convergence "one $x$ at a time" for *all* $x$ in the interval not "it is only required that there exists some $x$" as you say.

Comment: This is just a restatement of the definition

Comment: @Winther - I have edited my answer based on your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

You may think in this way: Let say we have a tube, in fact this should be range, then uniform convergence simply requires the diameter of the tube is sort of uniform at infinity.